# Polar transformation in iOS

Tags: ios, animation, core-graphics

Can anyone help me to achieve this kind of **animated transformation** through Core Graphics. Look at the rough sketch:

[image]

This is a simple chart graphic, and I need to transform a histogramm-style bar (left shape) to a pie chart (right shape).
Literally the task is to roll a rectangle to a ring with a **smooth animation**. I almost found the way to do this with a tricky queue of drawings, mask clippings and affine transformations but this won't look exactly how I want it to look.

Comment: Did you have a look at UIBezierPaths?, Potentially something like this `[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:(0,0,50,50)];` I am thinking to use one outer circle with colors and one inner circle that is white, the problem would be that the inner circle is not transparent so it would only make sense on backgrounds that aren't gradients or show content

Comment: @Benzy the question is how to `roll` a rectangle to a ring. I'm familiar with Bezier path but I can't imagine how can it help in this situation.

Comment: You need to play with CALayer, CATransformLayer... See some sample https://github.com/scotteg/LayerPlayer

Comment: This is just 3 different line arcs that start and end at different places and have different colours. You can do this with UIBezierPath and then use either CAShapeLayers or drawRect to put it on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting challenge, especially as you want to maintain the different segments. I won't give you a full answer (i.e full example code to achieving this), but I will explain what I think needs to be done to achieve the effect that you want.

### Paths

First, I see both of these diagrams as a single line that is stroked (let's ignore the segments for a moment), so the challenge is going from a straight line to an enclosed circle.

I propose the following two paths, that you can animate between to achieve a nice wrapping effect.

```
// As we render a circle as a chain of straight line segments
// changing the count of said segments makes the circle more or less smooth
// Try this with other values, such as 8 or 32
let segments = 72

// With this segment count, the angle of each segment in the circle is
let angle = (2 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / CGFloat(segments)

// First path (straight)
let length = CGFloat(300.0)
let segmentLength = length / CGFloat(segments)

let straightPath = CGPathCreateMutable()
CGPathMoveToPoint(straightPath, nil, 0.0, 0.0)
for i in 0...segments {
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(straightPath, nil, 0.0, CGFloat(i) * segmentLength)
}

// Second path (circle)
let radius = CGFloat(100.0)
let center = CGPoint(x: 104.0, y: 104.0)
let space = (x: 2.0, y: 2.0)

var circlePath = CGPathCreateMutable()
CGPathMoveToPoint(circlePath, nil, center.x + radius, center.y)
for i in 0...segments {
    let x = cos(-CGFloat(i) * angle)
    let y = sin(-CGFloat(i) * angle)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(circlePath, nil, center.x + radius * x, center.y + radius * y)
}
```

I have also uploaded a Swift plaground for you to experiment with, which you can find [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/50sf4urx7lhnylz/LineToCircle.playground.zip?dl=0)

### Segments

Now, handling the segments can be a bit tricky, however I propose a relatively naive implementation that might work. Mainly, `CAShapeLayer` has the following two properties - `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd`, which allow controlling the part of the path that is actually stroked.

With this in mind, you could create as many layers as there are segments, assign them all the same path(s) and tweak their respective `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd` properties to make it look the way you expect. Somewhat similar to what they do in [this post](http://subjc.com/spark-camera/).

### Animation

Assuming you have conquered the previous two aspects, the animation aspect should be relatively straight forward, using the two types of paths you have, you can create a simple `CABasicAnimation` that goes from one to another. I will assume you are familiar with CoreAnimation and its usage (i.e how to properly change model values to match those that are presented etc.).

I will end my answer with a quick animation showing what the end result could look like (minus the segments), I have frozen the animation and am manipulating the `timeOffset` property of the layer to manually scrub through it.

[image: Scrubbing through the potential animation]

I hope my answer helps you get closer to the solution you want. It is also important to emphasise that my code examples are just a beginning, you will likely need to tweak the values quite a bit to achieve a satisfying animation (for example, the length of the line should be similar to that of the circumference of the circle).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Really helpful, especially that part about animating transition from one path value to another. I didn't know this is possible. However, what do you think about animating bezier curves?

Comment: CAShapeLayer (the one I am referring to) only operates with CGPaths, but you can always get that from a UIBezierPath as well. The key to the animation being fluid is to have exactly the same number of points in both paths, as mentioned in the documentation - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAShapeLayer/path

Answer (score 0):

Skewing, twisting and bending are none trivial transformations on bodies.
These can't be done `Core Graphics`.

Better draw the chart yourself with `CGContextAddArcToPoint` in `core graphic` and mask out the inner circle.

The other (hardcore) way would be using a 3d engine - i.e. scene kit - and apply your chart as texture to it.